# What word means the "personification" of a place?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

An abstract concept can be *personified* as a human figure (like the Media, in Neil Gaiman's *American Gods*).

What equivalent word to "personification" could I use if I want to say that an abstract concept was being represented by a place/location?

Comment: Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Comment: The term 'genius loci' (spirit of [a] place) refers to a fanciful connection with sentient beings present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Embodiment** perhaps. Or you might find a synonym you like in a [thesaurus](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/embodiment).

Comment: @user405662: I wonder why you're asking ME. Did I mention the Bible recently? I may have done. Remind me where. To answer your question, I think all editions of the King James Bible have the same text: the same translation. The only differences will be in the additional maps, indices (or 'indexes') and footnotes they may include. There have been many different translations since the King James Version, but I prefer the language of the KJV.

Comment: I apolgize, Sir. I got confused.

Comment: @user405662 No need to apologize :-)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using “analogy”, though it is still a general term:

> A comparison between one thing and another, typically for the purpose of explanation or clarification. [lexico.com](https://www.lexico.com/definition/analogy)

Or "metaphor":

> A figure of speech in which a word or phrase is applied to an object or action to which it is not literally applicable. [lexico.com](https://www.lexico.com/definition/metaphor)

Answer (score -2):

Please refer to below. Maybe White House (in the US.), Blue House (in Korea) and Pentagon (in US.) will represent lots of things like power, corruption(?), melting pot, etc.(White House could also mean President)

From  [literarydevices.net/synecdoche](https://literarydevices.net/synecdoche):

> **Definition of Synecdoche**
> Synecdoche is a figure of speech in which a part of something is used to signify the whole, or vice-versa. In fact, it’s derived from the Greek word synekdoche: “simultaneous meaning.” As a literary device, synecdoche allows for a smaller component of something to stand in for the larger whole, in a rhetorical manner. Synecdoche can work in the opposite direction as well, in which the larger whole stands in for a smaller component of something. Synecdoche is a helpful device for writers to express a word or idea in a different way by using an aspect of that word or idea. This allows for variation of expression and produces an effect for the reader.
>
> For example, a common synecdoche for proposing marriage is to ask for a person’s “hand.” This is a figure of speech in the sense that asking for someone’s hand is for effect, not intended literally. The “hand” in this example of synecdoche is the part that signifies the whole person receiving the marriage proposal, and reflects the symbolic placement of a wedding ring. As a literary device, synecdoche is a means for writers to avoid overusing words or phrases and creating an artistic form of expression.
>
> **Common Examples of Synecdoche**
> Here are some examples of synecdoche that may be found in everyday expression:
>
> - The White House (signifies the U.S. president or executive branch)
> - Wearing heels (signifies high-heeled shoes)
> - Green thumb (signifies person who is good at gardening)
> - The Pentagon (signifies U.S. military leaders)
> - England (signifies Great Britain)
> - Boots on the ground (signifies soldiers)
> - Paper or plastic (signifies type of shopping bag)
> - Stars and stripes (signifies U.S. flag)
> - Suits (signifies people in business)
> - Wheels (signifies a vehicle)
> - Pearly gates (signifies Heaven)
>   Behind bars (signifies being in jail)
> - Threads (signifies clothing)
> - Tickle the ivories (signifies playing piano keys)
> - Twinkle toes (signifies a dancer)

Comment: Please refer to below. This answer explains how one piece can stand in for the whole, while the question wants to represent a concept as a physical piece.

Comment: A place/location represented an abstract concept (simple active voice).